# Mysql 5.5 to 5.7 - You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause - Same Table

Tags: mysql

Some queries that I had written for MySQL 5.5 no longer work for MySQL 5.7. I'm not sure if there is a configuration setting...

The following query is no longer valid:

```
Update Tablex set Column1 = 3 where Tablex.ID = 20 and not exists (
    Select * From ( Select * from Tablex a where a.StartTime > :Start and a.EndTime <:end ) as DerivedTable1
)
```

//You can't specify target table Tablex for update in FROM clause

This worked perfectly in MySQL 5.5, basically the idea is that MySQL would create a temp table...but now I guess not. Anyone know how to update this for MySQL 5.7? Alternatively I can use a transaction and pre-query the exists condition and then proceed based on the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's indeed a change in MySQL 5.7, described [**in the docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#idm140610710676192):

> The optimizer now handles derived tables and views in the `FROM` clause
>   in consistent fashion to better avoid unnecessary materialization and
>   to enable use of pushed-down conditions that produce more efficient
>   execution plans. However, for statements such as `DELETE` or `UPDATE` that
>   modify tables, using the merge strategy for a derived table that
>   previously was materialized can result in an `ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED`
>   error.
>
> The error occurs when merging a derived table into the outer query
>   block results in a statement that both selects from and modifies a
>   table. (Materialization does not cause the problem because, in effect,
>   it converts the derived table to a separate table.) To avoid this
>   error, disable the `derived_merge` flag of the`optimizer_switch` system
>   variable before executing the statement:

```
mysql> SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';
```

Another possible workaround is mentioned in [this thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76259):

> - Force the derived table to be materialized, e.g by adding `DISTINCT`
>     after `SELECT`, or adding a `LIMIT`.

This approach has been chosen by Rails developers to fix [the similar bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19359).

Comment: Let me check this out and i'll get back to you on the results.

Comment: Sure. As a sidenote, doesn't `TableX` have an key column? It might be faster if you turn `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * ...))` into `keyColumn NOT IN (SELECT keyColumn FROM (SELECT DISTINCT keyColumn ...)`.

Comment: Using the above query you'd be correct. The query presented is a slimmed down example of my actual query. But thank you. And, all scenarios seem to correctly work as you described. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

The workaround referenced in the answer from raina77ow is correct. However, not being able to execute this particular kind of query `UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM t...) AS _t ...);` is a bug that was introduced in 5.7.6 and fixed in 5.7.11.

Bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79333

[5.7.11 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-11.html#mysqld-5-7-11-bug) (search for 79333).

Comment: Thank you for noting that bug was fixed. It helped me a lot - apt-get update solved a problem: )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one query, using a join:

```
Update Tablex x left join
       Tablex x2
       on x2.id = x.id and x2.StartTime > :Start and x2.EndTime < :end
    set x.Column1 = 3
    where x.ID = 20 and x2.id is null;
```

This should work in both MySQL 5.5 and 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

@raina77ow is right.

you also can add a row at `/etc/my.cnf`

```
optimizer_switch=derived_merge=off
```

ps: I use rails, so I can't change the default behavior of rails.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by upgrading from 5.7.9 to the latest version now as I speak is 5.7.12 and the subquery workaround started working again.